# Check 2 input fields and a select field for changing after they all have been filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have 2 input fields and a select box. When someone fills in all 3 fields there has to be some calculation. Everytime on of these fields change when they are all filled, the calculation should be fired again.

I achieved to do this with just the select box like this.

```
function showPrice() {
    calculate();
    $('#overview').removeClass('hidden');
}


$(".select").on('change', function()
    {
        showPrice();
    }
);
```

But how can I do this with 3 elements from different types?

Comment: Do you want your calculation to occur only after your input fields lose focus, or do you want it to happen after every key click (as somebody is typing into the textbox) and upon any paste change?

Comment: After they lose focus. But only if they are filled in all three. And everytime they change of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that loops through all elements you want and returns true if all of them are filled.

This would be the basic code:

```
    function check(){
    var filled = true;
    $('input').each(function(inx,elem){
        if($(elem).val()=='')
            filled = false;
    });
    
    return filled;
}
```

Check a working example [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/lrojas94/1ttuj4fL/)

Note that I used text and file types, but that should do for any type.

Comment: But I want to do this with only 3 elements not all of them :o how can I just check for the 3?

Comment: put them inside the div and only do that work with the children of the div. For instance, let's say you have this: <div id='hey'>*inputs*<div>. Instead of using just $('input').each, use $('#hey').children('input').each.. Also, you can just add a class to the input

Comment: Here's a version of the code using classes: http://jsfiddle.net/lrojas94/1ttuj4fL/1/

Comment: My version is like this but it doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/enu0ju1h/ What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your return filled code was misplaced. It doesn't go inside the each function, it goes inside the isFilled() function. Just fixed that and it worked like a charm Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/lrojas94/qw5L0ufz/